# Simple DOM HTML returns wrong URL

Tags: php, html

I have the following code:

```
<?php

include("simple_html_dom.php");

crawl('http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&output=search&q=inurl:https://website.com/folder/');

function crawl($url){
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    $links = $html->find('a');
    foreach($links as $link)
    {
        $new_link = str_replace("url?q=", "/" ,$link->href);
        $new_link = $newstr = substr( $new_link, 0, strpos( $new_link, '&' ) );

        echo "<a href='".$new_link."'>".$link->plaintext."</a><br />";
    }
}

?>
```

it returns url like this: `http//website.com/folder/stuff`

without the `:` which makes the URL inaccessible.

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($links);`?

Comment: Not sure what voodoo SHD does... but what happens if you just use the `parse_url` & `parse_str` functions? BTW: I would think it would return something like `"/http://website.com/folder/stuff"`, where does your leading `/` disappear?

Comment: I have SHD installed and just ran your code. It works fine for me; all colons are present. You have something else going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is nothing wrong in your code here is my approach using `DOMDocument`

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
@$xml->loadHTMLFile("http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&output=search&q=inurl:https://github");
$links = array();
foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
    //skip if url don't contain url?q
    if (false === strpos($link->getAttribute('href'), '/url?q')) continue;

     $href = str_replace("url?q=", "/" ,$link->getAttribute('href'));
     $href = substr( $href, 0, strpos( $href, '&' ) );
     $links[] = array('url' => str_replace("//","", $href), 'text' => $link->nodeValue);
}

print_r($links);
```

See [Demo at Viper](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZUXYq4)

Answer (score -1):

What if you take out the "http://" all together?  Wouldn't it put you on the correct website?  I don't know php, but I'm going to take a guess based on what I know about HTML and how browsers work.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: Not only not an answer, also demonstrably wrong. `<a href="www.example.com/whatever">` does not point to the `www.example.com` domain, but rather to `http://whateversitethelinkis.on/www.example.com/whatever`.

Comment: Okay.  Told you guys I didn't know PHP, just a suggestion though.  I am waiting for an answer that has been approved so I can learn.